# How do I switch OnBase Current Document in VBScript to access each document from a list of Document Handles?

Tags: vbscript, document

I am attempting to:

1. Run a VBScript sql query (which I already know how to do) to get a list of OnBase Document Handles.
2. Then take each Document Handle and access the associated document (an OnBase E-Form)
3. Access each document's E-Form fields, extracting relevant non-keyword values and saving them to various database tables(which I also know how to do).

So the problem at hand is how to set the "Current Document" based on whichever document handle appears next.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, accessing the database directly from the script is a bad idea as modifying the database without Hyland's approval / oversight will void your warranty.  You should route it all directly through the OnBase API.  Which version of OnBase are you using?

I see this was asked in January.  If you respond to this, I'll know there's a point to continuing and can help more.